# How set get request with json body from soapui?

Tags: java, json, http, get, soapui

It is legal (in some cases) to send get request with json data contained in the body. But `soapui` hides "body" subwindow where I can paste json string so only key-value pairs menu is available. Is there any workaround to send get request with body in soapui?

Comment: Update to a later version. At some point this got fixed.

Comment: version 5.2.1 does not allow that.

Comment: I just checked and you are correct. I filed a bug with SmartBear about this sometime back, and they still have not fixed it in 5.2.1. In the -Pro (licensed) version you could do it using custom events: https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/custom-event-handlers.html

Comment: Even with v5.2.1 you cannot send json in GET method. You should try POSTMAN to do that

Comment: Installed the latest 5.3 and I don't see a fix. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You can add json, choose application/json as Media type, as shown below.
I use soapui release 4.5.1,free edition on linux.

[image]

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Are you ensure that it is for GET http method?

Comment: Sorry somehow it was not noticed. I believe that post method accepts payload in soapui. Are you sure that you can't get the data using parameters?

Comment: Sure :) Read about elasricsearch - attache body with GET method is common pratic on it.

Comment: @Cherry Have you tried using groovy's [RESTClient](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html). I havent tried with `GET` though. You can give it a shot.

Comment: No, I have not. Could you post an example with that?

Comment: @Rao are you able to take a look at this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390574/soapui-restful-service-questions . Thanks